# When does Angular trigger ngAfterContentChecked?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

According to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) the `AfterContentChecked` lifecycle hook is triggered:

> after Angular checks the content projected into the component

What does *"Angular checks"* in the documentation mean, exactly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[AfterContentChecked](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), component-only hook, is called after Angular checks the content projected into the component (it's data-bound properties).

When does Angular check the projected content?

- Initially, after the `AfterContentInit` hook finishes.
- Every time the change detection is run (application state change).

What causes the application state change?

- Events - *click, submit, …*
- Ajax calls - *fetching data from a remote server*
- Timers - *setTimeout, setInterval*

See also: [Angular change detection explained](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html).